# How can I remove a string of text from a files name?

Tags: files, rename

Following [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209449/is-there-a-way-to-batch-export-svgs-to-pngs) I exported various SVGs to PNGs, but there is a little problem, all files include in their name the extensions .svg and .png as in `file.svg.png`.

Now what I'd like to know is how can I remove the .svg string from the name of the file *without* going trough each file and do right-click>rename?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pyrenamer` is a pretty handy tool for batch renaming files. Otherwise, you could always fire up the terminal.

```bash
for file in *; do mv "${file}" "${file//\.svg/}"; done
```

That should do the trick if you're in the same directory as the pictures. Use at own risk.

Answer (score 11):

I guess this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58546/batch-rename-files) to another question could help :)

Specific to the question:

`rename s/".svg"/""/g *`

General:

`rename s/"**TO-BE-REPLACED**"/"**REPLACEMENT**"/g *`

Comment: Thunar's rename tool is pretty much what I wanted yes, it helped. I wiil up-vote you as you lead me to it but not exactly solved it ;) perhaps you should add it.

Comment: Please check the version of ```rename``` before using it. https://askubuntu.com/a/1024963/542527