# rename not working

Tags: bash, rename, filename

I have a bunch of files with names like

```
... (Karton 1).jpeg
```

and would like to rename them recursively to:

```
... (brauner Karton).jpeg
```

I tried the following commands, which didn't work:

```
rename -v 's/Karton 1/brauner Karton/g' *
rename -v 's/Karton 1/brauner Karton/g' *.jpeg
```

According to a lot of examples this shouldn't be that hard. What am I doing wrong?

Aditional info: "Karton 1" would be "[B/b]ox 1" in English.

Comment: What exactly happened? Was there any output? You may be using the wrong `rename`... You don't need to escape spaces in regex, btw. Also, please show your real filenames - do not add quotes, `.` characters etc that are not really there!

Comment: Version is 2.31.1 (util-linux).

Comment: Try `rename -n ...` first. What does it show?

Comment: No output. Also not with rename -n -v

Comment: if no output, means you don't have a file that match with what you are trying to rename. Likely you already rename it before too.

Comment: rename.ul is the wrong `rename` for this syntax. You need Perl `rename` (`file-rename`). Are you using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 14):

There are [several](https://askubuntu.com/questions/956010/whats-the-difference-between-the-different-rename-commands) versions of the rename command.  Use `rename --version` to determine which you have, they use different syntax.

```
$ rename --version
/usr/bin/rename using File::Rename version 0.20
$ rename 's/\.jpeg$/.jpg/' *

$ rename --version
rename from util-linux 2.30.2
$ rename .jpeg .jpg *
```

Comment: I think you and the OP are talking about different utilities. And wonder which one he actually has.

Comment: He's got the one I have.  Mine is util-linux 2.30.2, I ran into this issue a year ago and couldn't figure out how to get rename to work again...if I had only looked at the man page.

Comment: Ok. Because there's also one with _his_ syntax.

Comment: I know, I used to use it, trying to figure out when/why that changed.