# Git gui here script

Tags: 12.10, command-line, gnome-terminal, git, context-menu

I want to open git gui in any folder using context menu. It something like

```
cd <path to folder>
git gui
```

in terminal.

How to add this functionality into context menu?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a nautilus script for that.
Just create your script like:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$1" && git gui
```

After installing it, you will be able to right-click a folder, and choose `Scripts → Your Script Here`. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236414/how-do-i-install-a-nautilus-script) for how to install the script.