# Is it possible to have Nautilus Scripts menu items without icons?

Tags: nautilus-script, nautilus

I have opted for menus without icons system-wide for reasons of simplicity and speed.

But I still get icons in **Nautilus** context menus. I don't mind the icons on **Open With** menu items too much, but all those **identical icons** on **Nautilus Scripts** (especially when you have  many scripts) look ugly.

I wonder if there's a way of **disabling these icons** at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an interim solution, i.e. to avoid identical script icons (in the absence of a way of disabling display of icons) **different and more relevant icons** can be set for Nautilus Scripts using this command pattern:

```
gvfs-set-attribute -t string "<Your-Nautilus-Script-File-Path>" metadata::custom-icon file:///usr/share/icons/<Your-Coice-of-Individual-Icon>
```

**Note: Another trick to get rid of those icons can be assigning non-existent icons, upon which no icon is displayed in the Scripts menu!**