# How can I quickly convert a GIF file to a video?

Tags: video, conversion, mp4, video-conversion, gif

I have a small animation formatted as a GIF image file which I would like to convert to a video. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using a Nautilus Script

---

**Overview**

You can easily convert GIF files to videos by using the `imagemagick` suite and `avconv`. To make the process easier I have written a small Nautilus script that takes your GIF file and the desired framerate as its input and outputs an MP4 file.

**Code**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# NAME          gif2mp4 0.1
# AUTHOR        Glutanimate (c) 2013 (https://askubuntu.com/users/81372/glutanimate)
# LICENSE       GNU GPL v3 (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html)
# DESCRIPTION   Converts GIF files of a specific framerate to MP4 video files.
# DEPENDENCIES  zenity,imagemagick,avconv

TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
FPS=$(zenity --width 200 --height 100 --entry --title "gif2mp4" --text="Please enter the frame rate.")
VIDDIR=$(dirname $1)

if [ -z "$FPS" ]
  then
      exit
fi

notify-send -i video-x-generic.png "gif2mp4" "Converting $(basename "$1") ..."

convert "$1" $TMPDIR/frame%02d.png
avconv -r $FPS -i $TMPDIR/frame%02d.png -qscale 4 "$VIDDIR/$(basename "$1" .gif).mp4"

notify-send -i video-x-generic.png "gif2mp4" "$(basename "$1") converted"

rm -rf $TMPDIR
```

**Installation instructions**

Please see here for more information on how to install this script: [How can I install a Nautilus script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236414/how-do-i-install-a-nautilus-script)