# How do I integrate Periscope with Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, subtitle

How do I fully integrate Periscope with Nautilus so that I can right-click on a video file and get subtitles downloaded?
I have downloaded all the appropriate files and Periscope is fully installed. The problem is getting it fully integrated with Nautilus or something like Nautilus. I do not want to operate at the the console

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple Nautilus script that should do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash

# NAME:         Get_subtitles   
# AUTHOR:       (c) 2014 Glutanimate   
# DEPENDENCIES: periscope (https://code.google.com/p/periscope/)
# LICENSE:      MIT license (http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)     

LANGUAGE="en"

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    MOVIE="$1"
    periscope "$MOVIE" -l "$LANGUAGE"
    shift
done
```

[Installation instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236414/how-can-i-install-a-nautilus-script/236415).

Note: I don't have periscope installed so I'd appreciate your feedback on whether the script works or not.

Comment: hi...many thanks for your work!...but i cant get it to download! i tried with 'periscope', then with 'periscope-gnome' and then with 'python-periscope'. no luck....and the video i tried it on i know has at least one English subtitle...what should we do now?

Comment: I think it's important first to check if **periscope** itself is working (mine is not) by entering a terminal command like this: `periscope -l en <movie-file>`

Comment: You are on to something!I tried Periscope on 3 French language movies that I know have English subtitles and it gave me nada! Can Periscope be fixed or has its author abandoned it? I tried contacting him and have received no reply!

Answer (score 0):

Here is [one particular way](https://code.google.com/p/periscope/wiki/NautilusSupport) to do this:

First up, install python support in nautilus by installing python-nautilus and python-notify:

```
sudo aptitude install python-nautilus python-notify
```

Then install [periscope](http://code.google.com/p/periscope/).

Now you need to copy the periscope-nautilus.py script into the ~/.nautilus/python-extensions folder:

```
cd ~/.nautilus/python-extensions
wget http://periscope.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bin/periscope-nautilus/periscope-nautilus.py
```

If you want to change the default languages, run periscope once, a file named "config" will be created under ~/.config/periscope. Update this file to reflect your preferred languages. (English example below, you can use commas to have multiple languages)

```
lang = en
```

Restart nautilus.

```
nautilus -q
```

Open nautilus and go find a video file, right click and now you've got the notification to see if corresponding subtitles were found.

Comment: Thanks. But I have tried this as well as all other methods posted on the forums and nothing works. Rumor has it that the integration works on Nemo or Thunar....