# Is it possible to duplicate a file or folder in nautilus directly?

Tags: nautilus

As of right now, if I want to duplicate a folder or file, I right click on it, choose 'copy', click on nautilus itself to change focus from current folder/file, right click somewhere else and choose 'paste'.

Is it possible to duplicate a folder or file directly, like through a 'right click' -> 'duplicate' in nautilus?

Comment: You want something faster than Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V ?

Comment: @AdityaPatil Hahah. Yah. Am a touchpad user and not a keyboard user. That's why.

Comment: You can make a plugin for nautilus that does just that

Comment: You can also CTRL + drag a file/folder to create a copy. But that would require keyboard input, I guess.

Comment: @Glutanimate Wow, didn't even know zat. It's awesome. Pressing just one key doesn't make me 'a keyboard guru' :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Inbuilt shortcut**

You can drag files while holding down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> to copy them.

**Keyboard independent solution using a Nautilus script**

Here's a short Nautilus script that should cover your use case:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#Nautilus script to duplicate selected files/folders

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do

    echo "$# file(s)/folder(s) left to duplicate."
    ORIGINALITEM="$1"    
    DUPLICATEITEM="${ORIGINALITEM} (copy)"
    cp -r "$ORIGINALITEM" "$DUPLICATEITEM"
    shift

done
echo "Done."
```

[Installation instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236414/how-can-i-install-a-nautilus-script)

**Note**: This is a very simple script and will fail if a duplicate file of the same naming scheme already exists in the same directory. It's also not as elegant as the naming Nautilus does by default ( *(copy)* is inserted after the extension).