# How do I make new Nautilus windows show the same folder as the original window?

Tags: nautilus

I want to achieve the following:

- I have a Nautilus windows showing the /foo/bar dir.
- I hit Ctrl+n (new window).
- I want the new window to show /foo/bar instead of my home dir.

Comment: Why not use a tab instead- Ctrl + t?

Comment: It is easier to drag'n'drop between windows than tabs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no option for changing or customizing the New Window action behavior.

But you can create a nautilus script with the behavior you want and use it *instead* of the built in action. It's a one-liner that simply opens Nautilus at a given folder. In your case, the *current* folder. Save the script at `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts` (`~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` for Ubuntu 13.04 onwards).

To invoke such script with <kbd>CTRL+N</kbd> you must edit `~/.gnome2/accels/nautilus` (`~/.local/share/nautilus/accels` for 13.04+) and edit the corresponding lines for both your script and New Window builtin action.

You could also request this feature at gnome buglist for Nautilus:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/browse.cgi?product=nautilus

Answer (score 2):

This Nautilus script should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash
# opens new Nautilus window showing the same folder

nautilus "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI"
```

[General installation instructions for Nautilus scripts and assigning Nautilus keyboard shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/a/236415/81372).

Comment: @MestreLion Well, keyboard assignments do work on older releases of Ubuntu but you are right, we didn't really have a canonical answer concerning keyboard shortcuts for Nautilus. I edited my generic installation instructions to add a section on that.

Comment: Wow, fantastic! Your updated answer has all the pieces of the puzzle. It should be the accepted answer, at least until someone (either of us?) post the details for his specific scenario